# ERROR in main.xxx.js from UglifyJs Invalid assignment [main.xxx.js:114163,30]

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, react-boilerplate

When running the command: `npm run build` I get this error:

```
clean-webpack-plugin: ..../internals/webpack/build has been removed.
Hash: e392cba8ffe45d4ccf3e                                                                
Version: webpack 3.5.5
Time: 25347ms
                                    Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
                            .htaccess.bin    1.79 kB          [emitted]  
                            manifest.json  570 bytes          [emitted]  
          0.4c78ff730ee413b0f722.chunk.js      41 kB       0  [emitted]  
          1.e85494ada20960940da1.chunk.js    2.42 kB       1  [emitted]  
          2.fbee78dcf2d2eb0c7313.chunk.js    3.47 kB       2  [emitted]  
          3.20d0e2989b358867fdd4.chunk.js    24.1 kB       3  [emitted]  
             main.0a7a3dfce71c313b3759.js    4.98 MB       4  [emitted]  main
main.7e2d77a8bd40ea6ad93420543f986fde.css    77.8 kB       4  [emitted]  main
                               index.html    1.67 kB          [emitted]  
                                    sw.js    17.8 kB          [emitted]  

ERROR in main.0a7a3dfce71c313b3759.js from UglifyJs
Invalid assignment [main.0a7a3dfce71c313b3759.js:114163,30]

Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
     1 asset
Child __offline_serviceworker:
     1 asset
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! react-boilerplate@3.5.0 build: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js --color -p --progress --hide-modules --display-optimization-bailout`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the react-boilerplate@3.5.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

### Here is my package.json

```js
{
  "name": "react-boilerplate",
  "version": "3.5.0",
  "description": "A highly scalable, offline-first foundation with the best DX and a focus on performance and best practices",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate.git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "npm": ">=3",
    "node": ">=5"
  },
  "author": "Max Stoiber",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "analyze:clean": "rimraf stats.json",
    "preanalyze": "npm run analyze:clean",
    "analyze": "node ./internals/scripts/analyze.js",
    "extract-intl": "babel-node --presets env,stage-0 -- ./internals/scripts/extract-intl.js",
    "npmcheckversion": "node ./internals/scripts/npmcheckversion.js",
    "preinstall": "npm run npmcheckversion",
    "postinstall": "npm run build:dll",
    "prebuild": "npm run build:clean",
    "build": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js --color -p --progress --hide-modules --display-optimization-bailout",
    "build:clean": "rimraf ./build",
    "build:dll": "node ./internals/scripts/dependencies.js",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node server",
    "start:tunnel": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development ENABLE_TUNNEL=true node server",
    "start:production": "npm run test && npm run build && npm run start:prod",
    "start:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server",
    "presetup": "npm i chalk shelljs",
    "setup": "node ./internals/scripts/setup.js",
    "postsetup": "npm run build:dll",
    "clean": "shjs ./internals/scripts/clean.js",
    "clean:all": "npm run analyze:clean && npm run test:clean && npm run build:clean",
    "generate": "plop --plopfile internals/generators/index.js",
    "lint": "npm run lint:js",
    "lint:eslint": "eslint --ignore-path .gitignore --ignore-pattern internals/scripts",
    "lint:js": "npm run lint:eslint -- . ",
    "lint:staged": "lint-staged",
    "pretest": "npm run test:clean && npm run lint",
    "test:clean": "rimraf ./coverage",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --coverage",
    "test:watch": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --watchAll",
    "coveralls": "cat ./coverage/lcov.info | coveralls"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.js": "lint:eslint"
  },
  "pre-commit": "lint:staged",
  "babel": {
    "plugins": [
      "styled-components"
    ],
    "presets": [
      [
        "env",
        {
          "modules": false
        }
      ],
      "react",
      "stage-0"
    ],
    "env": {
      "production": {
        "only": [
          "app"
        ],
        "plugins": [
          "transform-react-remove-prop-types",
          "transform-react-constant-elements",
          "transform-react-inline-elements"
        ]
      },
      "test": {
        "plugins": [
          "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs",
          "dynamic-import-node"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint",
    "extends": "airbnb",
    "env": {
      "browser": true,
      "node": true,
      "jest": true,
      "es6": true
    },
    "plugins": [
      "redux-saga",
      "react",
      "jsx-a11y"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "ecmaVersion": 6,
      "sourceType": "module",
      "ecmaFeatures": {
        "jsx": true
      }
    },
    "rules": {
      "arrow-parens": [
        "error",
        "always"
      ],
      "arrow-body-style": [
        2,
        "as-needed"
      ],
      "class-methods-use-this": 0,
      "comma-dangle": [
        2,
        "always-multiline"
      ],
      "import/imports-first": 0,
      "import/newline-after-import": 0,
      "import/no-dynamic-require": 0,
      "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": 0,
      "import/no-named-as-default": 0,
      "import/no-unresolved": 2,
      "import/no-webpack-loader-syntax": 0,
      "import/prefer-default-export": 0,
      "indent": [
        2,
        2,
        {
          "SwitchCase": 1
        }
      ],
      "jsx-a11y/aria-props": 2,
      "jsx-a11y/heading-has-content": 0,
      "jsx-a11y/href-no-hash": 2,
      "jsx-a11y/label-has-for": 2,
      "jsx-a11y/mouse-events-have-key-events": 2,
      "jsx-a11y/role-has-required-aria-props": 2,
      "jsx-a11y/role-supports-aria-props": 2,
      "max-len": 0,
      "newline-per-chained-call": 0,
      "no-confusing-arrow": 0,
      "no-console": 1,
      "no-use-before-define": 0,
      "prefer-template": 2,
      "react/forbid-prop-types": 0,
      "react/jsx-first-prop-new-line": [
        2,
        "multiline"
      ],
      "react/jsx-filename-extension": 0,
      "react/jsx-no-target-blank": 0,
      "react/require-default-props": 0,
      "react/require-extension": 0,
      "react/self-closing-comp": 0,
      "redux-saga/no-yield-in-race": 2,
      "redux-saga/yield-effects": 2,
      "require-yield": 0
    },
    "settings": {
      "import/resolver": {
        "webpack": {
          "config": "./internals/webpack/webpack.prod.babel.js"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "dllPlugin": {
    "path": "node_modules/react-boilerplate-dlls",
    "exclude": [
      "chalk",
      "compression",
      "cross-env",
      "express",
      "ip",
      "minimist",
      "sanitize.css"
    ],
    "include": [
      "core-js",
      "lodash",
      "eventsource-polyfill"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "app/**/*.{js,jsx}",
      "!app/**/*.test.{js,jsx}",
      "!app/*/RbGenerated*/*.{js,jsx}",
      "!app/app.js",
      "!app/global-styles.js",
      "!app/*/*/Loadable.{js,jsx}"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "statements": 98,
        "branches": 91,
        "functions": 98,
        "lines": 98
      }
    },
    "moduleDirectories": [
      "node_modules",
      "app"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      ".*\\.(css|less|styl|scss|sass)$": "<rootDir>/internals/mocks/cssModule.js",
      ".*\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/internals/mocks/image.js"
    },
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/internals/testing/test-bundler.js",
    "testRegex": "tests/.*\\.test\\.js$"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.8",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "0.0.18",
    "@material-ui/core": "^1.4.2",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^1.1.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "chalk": "1.1.3",
    "child_process": "1.0.2",
    "cls-bluebird": "^2.1.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.3",
    "cross-env": "5.0.0",
    "email-validator": "^2.0.4",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "fontfaceobserver": "2.0.9",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "hoist-non-react-statics": "2.1.1",
    "immutable": "3.8.1",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "invariant": "2.2.2",
    "ip": "1.1.5",
    "js-file-download": "^0.4.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "marquee-react-dwyer": "^5.7.9",
    "material-ui": "^1.0.0-beta.46",
    "minimist": "1.2.0",
    "net": "^1.0.2",
    "prop-types": "15.5.10",
    "query-string": "^6.2.0",
    "re-carousel": "^2.0.9",
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-addons-css-transition-group": "^15.6.2",
    "react-countdown-now": "^1.3.0",
    "react-device-detect": "^1.5.9",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-helmet": "5.1.3",
    "react-html-parser": "^2.0.2",
    "react-intl": "2.3.0",
    "react-loadable": "4.0.3",
    "react-marquee": "^0.1.1",
    "react-paypal-express-checkout": "^1.0.4",
    "react-redux": "5.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "4.1.1",
    "react-router-redux": "5.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-smooth-marquee": "^1.0.0",
    "react-sticky-el": "^1.0.20",
    "react-swipeable-views": "^0.12.16",
    "react-text-marquee": "^1.0.1",
    "react-text-mask": "^5.4.3",
    "react-tooltip": "^3.6.1",
    "redux": "3.6.0",
    "redux-immutable": "4.0.0",
    "redux-localstorage": "^0.4.1",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-saga": "^0.15.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "reselect": "3.0.1",
    "sanitize.css": "4.1.0",
    "scroll-events": "^1.1.3",
    "styled-components": "2.0.0",
    "tls": "0.0.1",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "warning": "3.0.0",
    "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "2.0.1",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^1.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-intl": "2.3.1",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "2.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "1.1.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-classes": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-function-name": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-assign": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "6.23.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "0.4.5",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-3": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "circular-dependency-plugin": "3.0.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "0.1.17",
    "coveralls": "^3.0.2",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "enzyme": "2.8.2",
    "eslint": "3.19.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "15.0.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "11.2.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "0.8.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.7.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-redux-saga": "0.3.0",
    "eventsource-polyfill": "0.9.6",
    "exports-loader": "0.6.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.1",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^4.5.0",
    "imports-loader": "0.7.1",
    "jest-cli": "^23.6.0",
    "lint-staged": "3.5.1",
    "ngrok": "2.2.9",
    "node-plop": "0.7.0",
    "null-loader": "0.1.1",
    "offline-plugin": "^5.0.5",
    "plop": "1.8.0",
    "pre-commit": "1.2.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.6.1",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "shelljs": "0.7.7",
    "style-loader": "0.18.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "3.5.5",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "1.11.0",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.0"
  }
}
```

#### Here is the webpack.base.babel.js

```js
/**
 * COMMON WEBPACK CONFIGURATION
 */

const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

// Remove this line once the following warning goes away (it was meant for webpack loader authors not users):
// 'DeprecationWarning: loaderUtils.parseQuery() received a non-string value which can be problematic,
// see https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils/issues/56 parseQuery() will be replaced with getOptions()
// in the next major version of loader-utils.'
// process.noDeprecation = true;

module.exports = (options) => ({
  entry: options.entry,
  output: Object.assign({ // Compile into js/build.js
    path: path.resolve(process.cwd(), 'build'),
    publicPath: '/',
  }, options.output), // Merge with env dependent settings
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/, // Transform all .js files required somewhere with Babel
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: { 
            plugins: [
              "transform-object-assign",
              ["transform-es2015-arrow-functions", { "spec": true }],
              ["transform-class-properties", { "spec": true }],
              'transform-es2015-classes',
              'transform-es2015-modules-commonjs',
              'transform-es2015-function-name',
            ],
            presets: ["es2015", "stage-2", "react" ]
          },
        },
      },
      {
        // Preprocess our own .css files
        // This is the place to add your own loaders (e.g. sass/less etc.)
        // for a list of loaders, see https://webpack.js.org/loaders/#styling
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        // use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
        use: options.cssLoaders,
      },
      {
        // Preprocess 3rd party .css files located in node_modules
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: /node_modules/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(eot|svg|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        use: 'file-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
        use: [
          'file-loader',
          {
            loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
            options: {
              progressive: true,
              optimizationLevel: 7,
              interlaced: false,
              pngquant: {
                quality: '65-90',
                speed: 4,
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: 'html-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        use: 'json-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.(mp4|webm)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 10000,
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: options.plugins.concat([
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      // make fetch available
      fetch: 'exports-loader?self.fetch!whatwg-fetch',
    }),

    // Always expose NODE_ENV to webpack, in order to use `process.env.NODE_ENV`
    // inside your code for any environment checks; UglifyJS will automatically
    // drop any unreachable code.
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
      },
    }),
    new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
  ]),
  resolve: {
    modules: ['app', 'node_modules'],
    extensions: [
      '.js',
      '.jsx',
      '.react.js',
    ],
    mainFields: [
      'browser',
      'jsnext:main',
      'main',
    ],
  },
  devtool: options.devtool,
  target: 'web', // Make web variables accessible to webpack, e.g. window
  performance: options.performance || {},
});
```

#### Here is the webpack.prod.babel.js

```js
// Important modules this config uses
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const OfflinePlugin = require('offline-plugin');
const Clean = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = require('./webpack.base.babel')({
  // In production, we skip all hot-reloading stuff
  entry: [
    path.join(process.cwd(), 'app/app.js'),
  ],

  // Utilize long-term caching by adding content hashes (not compilation hashes) to compiled assets
  output: {
    filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].[chunkhash].chunk.js',
  },

  // We use ExtractTextPlugin so we get a seperate CSS file instead
  // of the CSS being in the JS and injected as a style tag
  cssLoaders: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        camelCase: true,
        modules: true,
        importLoaders: 1,
      },
    },
  }),

  plugins: [
    new Clean(['build']),
    new webpack.optimize.ModuleConcatenationPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: '[name].[contenthash].css',
      ignoreOrder: true,
      allChunks: true,
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      children: true,
      minChunks: 2,
      async: true,
    }),

    // Minify and optimize the index.html
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'app/404.html',
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
        keepClosingSlash: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyURLs: true,
      },
      inject: true,
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'app/index.html',
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
        keepClosingSlash: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyURLs: true,
      },
      inject: true,
    }),  

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'app/500.html',
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
        keepClosingSlash: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyURLs: true,
      },
      inject: true,
    }),

    // Put it in the end to capture all the HtmlWebpackPlugin's
    // assets manipulations and do leak its manipulations to HtmlWebpackPlugin
    new OfflinePlugin({
      relativePaths: false,
      publicPath: '/',

      // No need to cache .htaccess. See http://mxs.is/googmp,
      // this is applied before any match in `caches` section
      excludes: ['.htaccess'],

      caches: {
        main: [':rest:'],

        // All chunks marked as `additional`, loaded after main section
        // and do not prevent SW to install. Change to `optional` if
        // do not want them to be preloaded at all (cached only when first loaded)
        additional: ['*.chunk.js'],
      },

      // Removes warning for about `additional` section usage
      safeToUseOptionalCaches: true,

      AppCache: false,
    }),
  ],

  performance: {
    assetFilter: (assetFilename) => !(/(\.map$)|(^(main\.|favicon\.))/.test(assetFilename)),
  },
});
```

#### Tried options:

1. I have tried to add modules to precompile the code down first, as a lot of posts seem to say that uglifyJS only reads ES5. I have tried all the ones I can think of that are relevant. Maybe I missed one?
2. I have also tried to re-order the plugins in the `webpack.base.babel.js` file. and reorder the presets as well. Either nothing happens or it brings up another error of the same kind.

***It's probably something small.. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
Or how to fix?***

*Versions*
*React-Boilerplate: 3.5.0*
*Node/NPM: 6.1.0*

Comment: Im running into the same error and wanted check if you found a fix @waz

Comment: @TarunKolla Sorry, I can't actually remember the details. Sorry. I have a feeling that I may have had to get the latest versions of everything. Sorry I couldn't be more help.